# react onChange function does not work for select tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have had this issue for a while so i'm hoping to find an ansewer here. I tried to implement a simple select tag based on [the code given in the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). However, this does not work for me. Here is the code that I have written:

```
<select value={this.state.formId} onChange={this.handleInternalFormChange}>
                        {
                            Object.keys(this.state.userForms).map(formKey => ( 
                                <option key={formKey} value={formKey} > {this.state.userForms[formKey]} </option>
                            ))
                        }
```

and here is the function that calls onChange,

```
 handleInternalFormChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            formId: e.target.value
        })
        console.log(this.state.formId);

    }
```

Upon having made these changes, the onChange function does not seem to work. i tried to print out the event that is called but it doesn't seem to contain a `target`. Not sure what to do anymore, can someone help with this?

Comment: If your problem is console.log, you can't get the changed e.target.value. Because the setState function is asynchronous. You have to use callback function.

Comment: Have you consoled out the `e.target.value`? There is nothing wrong with the way you are doing it. You can confirm yourself by checking `onChange={e=>console.log(e)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the way you are currently doing it. 
The reason your `console.log()` is not printing out the state is because `setState()` is asynchronous (`console.log()` is also asynchronous by the way). If you would like to see what the updated state is, use `setState()`'s second parameter, which provides you with the new value.

You can confirm that the event is being used in `onChnage()` by replacing your function call with:

```
<select onChange={e=>console.log(e.target.value)}>
```

If you want to check the value after your state is updated do:

```
this.setState({value}, updatedState=>console.log(updatedState));
```

Hope that helps clear things up,

Comment: Yep, this make sense. I realized that right after I had called set state in `handleInternalFormChange`, I was calling setState in a function immediately after in a different function. This was probably the issue

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get `console.log` result, check this

```
 handleInternalFormChange = (e) =>{
        this.setState({
            formId: e.target.value
        }, () => {
           console.log(this.state.formId);
        })

    }
```